# Classes estáticas são compartilhadas por threads?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, concorrência

Classes, métodos e propriedades estáticas são compartilhadas entre as *threads* da aplicação?

Isto é, se eu modificar a propriedade estática `foo` na `ThreadA`, e em seguida modificar a mesma propriedade estática `foo` na `ThreadB`, qual será o valor da propriedade `foo`? Será diferente para cada `thread` ou o valor definido na `ThreadB` prevalecerá? Neste último caso, existe alguma configuração que possa ser realizada para definir que a classe estática será por *thread*?

Comment: Vou dar uma resposta para a 1a. parte, a 2a, seria melhor detalhar mais.

Comment: Vinicius, acho que poderia desmembrar essa pergunta em duas. Visto que uma é uma dúvida de `C#` e a outra de `Web API`.

Comment: @bigown atualizei a pergunta com novos detalhes, caso ache melhor uma nova pergunta como Randrade sugeriu, faço ela. Precisa de algum detalhe mais específico?

Comment: @Vinícius talvez seja mesmo, mas precisa detalhar bem mais. Em termos gerais, até mesmo sobre o problema real eu já estou falando. Mas a solução mais específica ainda não dá pra responder. Se tornar mais específico ainda, talvez a pergunta fique muito ampla. Então aqui talvez seja legal para entender o geral e a solução específica pode ficar em outro lugar. Mas reafirmo, coloque código, ou algo que dê para entender melhor o que ocorre de fato.

Comment: O seu problema real pode ser melhor solucionado se você de fato adotar uma arquitetura Onion! A parte removida da pergunta indica que você possui camadas empilhadas, com a camada de negócios conhecendo a camada de dados, e não uma arquitetura Onion de fato. Numa arquitetura Onion o contexto de persistência seria configurado pela camada de aplicativo e injetado na camada de negócio a cada requisição, com seu escopo limitado àquela requisição, e você não precisaria se preocupar com requisições simultâneas (threads). Difícil detalher num comentário e você removeu a parte relevante desta pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, são compartilhadas por toda aplicação, independente de *threads*. Por esse motivo dados estáticos são inerentemente **não** [*thread-safe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Um dos motivos que se costuma dizer para evitar o seu uso, ou quando o fizer, que faça de forma segura tomando o cuidado de sincronizar o acesso.

Acho que fica óbvio, que pelo menos para este aspecto, que objetos estáticos não são problemáticos se não tiver mais de uma *thread* na aplicação.

Se a propriedade não tiver estado não é um problema. Se o estado nunca pode ser mudado não é problema.

O valor da propriedade estática sempre será o último atribuído por qualquer uma das *threads*. No momento da mudança todas as *threads* enxergam o novo valor imediatamente já que é o mesmo local.

Note que em requisições de WebAPI, dependendo de como esteja configurado, você pode estar rodando instâncias diferentes da aplicação. Ou seja, processos diferentes, aí não tem comunicação alguma entre eles.

Se pretende criar uma classe estática como gambiarra para consertar um problema do *design* atual, eu recomendaria não fazer. Classes estáticas são ótimas quando elas fazem sentido, quando são realmente coisas únicas que devem ser globais. É preciso ter uma semântica (existem várias) para justificar seu uso.

O problema concreto ainda não está claro. Então é difícil dizer se este caso pode ser bem solucionado com o uso de uma classe estática. Mas me parece que o *thread pool* do WebAPI pode ser um complicador e eu não usaria isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

## Classes, métodos e propriedades estáticas são compartilhadas entre as threads da aplicação?

> Sim, mas não apenas membros estáticos como também qualquer membro de uma classe, estático ou não, pode ser compartilhado entre threads.

## Existe alguma configuração que possa ser realizada para definir que um valor será por thread?

> Sim. Você pode criar uma variável, estática ou não, que possua um valor exclusivo para cada thread, usando a classe [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx).

Exemplo:

```
static ThreadLocal<String> valorThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<string>();
```

Agora, um valor setado em `valorThreadLocal.Value` só será recuperado quando lido dentro da mesma thread que o setou, de modo que cada thread possui seu próprio valor em `valorThreadLocal`.

Dizemos, neste caso, que o valor de `valorThreadLocal` é local à thread corrente.